# Object Oriented vs Linear Programming

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am trying to write a program that allows a user to enter String values into  multiple methods that include arrayLists. I am having 2 issues:

1. My code seems linear (I want to ensure I am employing Object Oriented Programming principles).
2. I  am having difficulty writing the while loop required to add the values entered by the user into the arrayList. Since I don't know how many values will be entered, I figured that would be the approriate method to employ.

Here is what I have so far, your feedback is valued and appreciated :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Animals {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Here are some animal types! ");

    ArrayList<String> animalTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    animalTypes.add("Vertebrae");
    animalTypes.add("Reptile");
    animalTypes.add("Insect");
    animalTypes.add("Amphibian");
    System.out.println(" Enter new animal type");
    System.out.println(" Here is your animal types list! ");

   // This for loop is inadequate, I need a while loop as I don't know the exact number of entries from the user//
    for (int index = 0; index < animalTypes.size(); index++) {
        System.out.println(animalTypes.get(index));
    }
```

Comment: some logic like `while true, type quit to end`  User input can be obtained by Scanner.nextLine

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using procedural code when it makes your code easy to read. Object-oriented solutions are only good for object-oriented problems.

Comment: Unless you want to have duplicate animal types then may I suggest that you use a Set rather than an ArrayList

Comment: Well, there are certain requirements that need to be met for class. That means I have to create methods with arrayLists for each object, i.e animals class with objects (type, color, abilities, diet) . The user needs to be able to add/edit/delete to each object.

Comment: time to write an `Animal` class then.  If you have trouble search SO, and if you do not find a solution, create a new question.  BUT in the meantime, please upvote and/or accept the answers which addressed this question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Brandon's great answer which focuses much on the Animal type, OOP could be used for abstracting the `AnimalTypeInputter` class which could then be extended for other `TypeInputters` `addNewType` `listAllTypes` `findType` etc. Apart from the prompts, these methods could be inherited from a base `GenericTypeInputter`

Answer (score 1):

To all those, saying the problem is too small: Horsepoop! If you can't apply object orientation, principles or patterns to a small problem, you will not be able to apply them to a large problem. This example is actually nearly perfect!

To those who say you don't need Objects for this: Bullpoop!

Now there's a lot of principles we have to think about, for example:

- What if we would have a console client and a gui client, how to make our business logic *reusable* (even if it is just adding stuff to a list!)
- How do we *test* it! Because good code is as good as its test code and test code is as valuable as production code!
- How to we achieve *lose coupling* and *high cohesion*, or how do we apply the *single purpose pattern*

Now we analyze, what this code actually does, we split it into its *purposes*:

1. It tells the user, that he has a list of animals to choose, plain message
2. It reads the input from the user
3. It adds the user input to the animal list
4. (I guess) It shows all animals after the user input

I "would" do something like this... well, actually not, but for getting the idea, I would do it like this:

1. Write a `MessageShower` interface, with a method `showMessage(String message)`, if we think about different clients: for console client it sysout's, for e.g. a swing gui, it shows the message dialog thingie.
2. an interface `UserInputReader` with `String readInput()`
3. an interface `AnimalStorage` with `List<Animal> getAnimalList()` and `addAnimal(Animal newAnimal)`
4. an interface `AnimalDisplayer` with `showAnimals(List animalsToShow)

So we *decouple* the *purposes* from your main program and try to minimize/hide implementations to achieve *lose coupling*. We *isolate* them, to achieve *high cohesion*, so you can *test* not only them better, but also your main program, because you can *mock* the dependencies away, without having to test dependencies implicitly. Since they are isolated, they are easier to understand - their *purpose* is more clear - and therefore, the *purpose* of your main program will be easier to understand, too!

Answer (score 0):

To do Object Oriented Programming, you need objects.  If you don't need objects, then you're fine with normal/traditional structured coding.  I'm not sure the original problem needs OOP, not without some additional information as to what needs to be added.

(Not every problem lends itself to OOP. When you finally get to the point of using OOP, while inheritance is interesting, prefer using interfaces over inheritance.)

Answer (score 0):

> My code seems linear (I want to ensure I am employing Object Oriented Programming principles).

Making your code "more object oriented" would probably be **more effort than it's worth** for such a small program. It could bloat your program when it's quite readable enough already.

However, if you wanted to model different types of animals, you could use [inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html).

You could make:

- An `Animal` class.
- A bunch of "Animal Types" that inherit from `Animal` (e.g. `Reptile` or `Amphibian`)

Here is some *simplified* code to demonstrate that.

```
public class Animal {}
public class Vertebrate extends Animal {}
public class Reptile extends Animal {}
public class Insect extends Animal {}
public class Amphibian extends Animal {}
```

Because each of these "Animal Types" inherits from the `Animal` class, Java's Type System is *aware* that these are in fact animals, rather than Strings like you currently have.

This would allow you to write something like so...

```
ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Reptile());
animals.add(new Insect());
```

Be warned though, there's **really no point in this approach** since each of the classes are empty. But it *is* object oriented, like you've told us you want to achieve.

There's a right time and place for both procedural code and object oriented code. This is probably the right place for procedural code.

Comment: That answer would be fantastic for constructing a well-decoupled object oriented program, although I think it would go straight over their head. --- I think you should post it, because of the good advice it has on structuring OO code.

Comment: At your prompting I have added my comment as an answer

Comment: Thank you Brandon! this is a great suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

1) With a program so short, it's hard to fully make use of custom OOP, since you don't have any special objects, interfaces, etc. You're also not really violating OOP here either. OOP really comes into play when you have longer code that makes use of things like objects, where they would be useful and efficient, but in this case they aren't needed. Technically, you're still using OOP, since you're using things like ArrayList, Scanner, and System.

2) When taking in an unknown amount of input from console, a while loop is the right way to go. To detect when the user is done, I suggest using a *sentinel value*. This is a phrase that when detected, will cause your loop to stop via a break or return. Some examples of these would be "exit", or "stop." You'd check the input after they input it, and if it's this sentinel value, you would exit the loop:

```
while (true) {
   String text = Scanner.nextLine();
   if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("exit"))
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Animals {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Here are some animal types! ");

    String animals = "";

    boolean loopOne = true;
    char response;

    ArrayList<String> animalTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
    animalTypes.add("Vertebrae");
    animalTypes.add("Reptile");
    animalTypes.add("Insect");
    animalTypes.add("Amphibian");


    while(loopOne) {
        System.out.println("Do you wish to enter a new animal type ?");
        response = user.nextLine().charAt(0);

        if (response == 'n') {
            System.out.println("End of the program");
            loopOne = false;

        }

        else if (response == 'y') {
            System.out.println("Please enter your animal types");
            animals = user.nextLine();
            animalTypes.add(animals);               

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Error ! Please choose y (for yes) or n (for no)");
        }


    }

    System.out.println("\nHere's the list of the element in the ArrayList");
    for(int i = 0; i < animalTypes.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(animalTypes.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: Should use a Set not an ArrayList.  Should tabke `y` or `n` as case insensitive

Comment: Thank you so much guys, you have given me some great ideas! I very much appreciate it.